# How to push filter index and not list index in typescript angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have problem when I tried to filter and push item from a list to another list. The below push by index logic works without filter but when I filter out one item and click to push, it at first click pushes item of index 0 in the list and then pushes the filtered item at the second click.

I need help on how to modify my code so that when I filter, only the filtered item index would be pushed. See example here, to the right of page: [ListWithFilterExample](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list)

I want it so that when I filter out e.g "Billy" and click, then Billy is pushed and not first "Adele" which is list index 0 before "Billy" which is filter item 0.

**html**

```
<input class="" type="search" [(ngModel)]="filterFunction" placeholder="filter text here...">

<tr *ngFor="let item of ListB | filterBy: filterFunction; let i=index;">
    <td><button type="button" (click)="addItem(i)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
    </td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**ts**

```
addItem(i) {
  this.ListA.push(this.ListB[i]);
  this.ListB.splice(i, 1);
}
```

I have tried to map item to index but I still have the same problem. Is there a way in angular to bypass the ListB index whenever the filter input field has value of item to push?

Answer (score 0):

push there item instead.

```html
<button type="button" (click)="addItem(item)">
```

```js
addItem(item) {
  if (this.ListA.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    this.ListA.push(item);
  }
  if (this.ListB.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
    this.ListB.splice(this.ListB.indexOf(item), 1);
  }
}
```